# Use LINQ to Access All the Collections of a Collection on My Model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to write a property on my model, with only a get accessor that can return a collection that is comprised of all the collections that each member of a collection property contains.

So:

Document.Lines is a collection of Line objects. Each Line has a many to many relationship with Documents called RelatedDocuments. I would like to be able to access a collection of all the RelatedDocuments from every Line in the Document. Is there a way to do that in Linq/EF?

I am trying to do this without creating a dbContext object in the model.

Long form would be something like this:

```
  public List<RelatedDocument> RelatedDocuments
        {
            get
            {
                var RDs = new List<RelatedDocument>();
                foreach (var line in Lines)
                {
                    foreach (var rd in line.RelatedDocuments)
                    {
                        if (!RDs.Contains(rd))
                        {
                            RDs.Add(rd);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return RDs;
            }
        }
```

Comment: how do you plan to communicate with the DB without a DataContext?

Comment: EF generally requires a DBContext.  Are you planning on persisting these collections?

Comment: I'm in the model. I can access properties of the Lines collection, but since I'm in the model, I don't have access to things like SelectMany. I can probably iterate through the collection in long form and build a list but was hoping there was a more elegant linq based solution.

Comment: If it's an [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) collection, you do have access to [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx).

Comment: It's a List<T>. I edited above what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: So you just want a translation of this code to Linq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what the issue is; if `Lines` is `IEnumerable<T>` (*and* [`using System.Linq`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145016.aspx)), then wouldn't something like

```
var allRelated = Lines
  .SelectMany(line => line.RelatedDocuments)
  .Distinct();
```

suffice?

Of course, `Lines` itself has to come from somewhere ..

Comment: This looks promising. I think my problem was that I needed to import the namespace System.Linq. Since I was in a Model class, and a namespace that doesn't handle the data access, IntelliSense was showing me that those methods weren't available

Comment: @YHaber Yes, using the LINQ extension methods are a requirement (added that note to my answer). Consider trying ReSharper - cheap for commercial, free for non-commerical - as it will do the nifty "auto suggest import" on such errors. One potential issue with my answer is that [`Distinct` does not guarantee ordering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764978/linq-to-sql-does-not-generate-order-by-when-distinct-is-used).

Comment: I am using reSharper. THat's why, when I tried your code, I got the suggestion for the import! Before I was making assumptions based in the methods available in intellisense. I felt like I should be able to do select many, but it wasn't there.