# Order by in linq on joining

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have to show the movies which have most wanted to see status. For this I Join two tables 1. MovieInformation and 2. SeentItWantToSeeIt. I calculated most wanted to see movie with this code snippets.

```
public class RangkedMovieList
{
    public int MovieID { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
}

rankedList = db.SeenItWantToSeeIt.Where(m => m.Status == 1 && m.MovieID != null)
                                 .GroupBy(m => m.MovieID)
                                 .Select(g => new RangkedMovieList 
                                              {  MovieID = g.Key.Value,
                                                 count = g.Count() 
                                              })
                                 .ToList();
```

AllMovieInfo is Iqueryable with which I joined wanted to see movies.

```
AllMovieInfo = (from r in rankedList
                join a in AllMovieInfo on r.MovieID equals a.MovieID
                orderby r.count descending
                select a).Distinct().AsQueryable();
```

This query works fine and orders the result by MovieID but I want to order all movies by their wanted to see **count**. Though I have written code to *orderby r.count descending*, Its not working. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your second LINQ query is operating at the database level. If so, it's likely that the `Distinct` call won't honor the previously specified sort order (in fact, if you drop the `Distinct` call and debug your output, it should appear sorted correctly). Typically for simple queries you can fix this by swapping the order of the sort (i.e., `orderby`) and `Distinct` call while keeping the query on the database level, [as answered in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764978/linq-to-sql-does-not-generate-order-by-when-distinct-is-used), but your case is a little more complicated since you need to work with `rankingList`.

In your case you could bring it down to the LINQ to Objects level by adding a `ToList()` as you did for the first query, or an `AsEnumerable()`. At that level you wouldn't need to worry about swapping the order of the sort or distinct call. However, you'll likely need to use the [overloaded `Distinct` method that accepts an `IEqualityComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) and provide a comparer for `AllMovieInfo`. Check out the link for an example of how to implement that.

```
var query = (from r in rankedList
            join a in AllMovieInfo on r.MovieID equals a.MovieID
            select new { Info = a, Rank = r.count })
            .AsEnumerable()
            .OrderByDescending(o => o.Rank);
            .Select(o => o.Info)
            .Distinct(); // will likely need an IEqualityComparer here

// this could be combined with the above query, but I split it for clarity
AllMovieInfo = query.AsQueryable();
```

You might not need the `AsQueryable` at that point since it's already on the client at that point, in memory.

Comment: many many "Namaskar" from my home country Nepal. This code snippet worked exactly as I expected !