# VB LINQ: Order By doesn't work when used with Distinct

Tags: vb.net, linq

I know this is supposed to be a solved issue but I cannot get the documented solutions to work for me. The code below is suppose to do the order by after the distinct but it does not. I referred to this post: [LINQ to SQL does not generate ORDER BY when DISTINCT is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764978/linq-to-sql-does-not-generate-order-by-when-distinct-is-used)

```
fyMonth = (From f In DbContext.FYMonth
           Select f.Month).Distinct().OrderBy(Function(n) n).ToList()
```

I get an error when I try:

```
OrderBy(Function(n) n.SortOrder)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Oh, you can't use n.SortOrder in the orderby, because you didn't include it in your result set... you are only selecting Month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is selecting months and you're getting the distinct months.  A month does not contain a `SortOrder` property, you no longer have access to that property on your `FYMonth` objects.  You'll need to include the `SortOrder` into your projection, distinct then sort it, then project back to the month.

```
fyMonth = DbContext.FYMonth
    .Select(Function(x) New With { x.Month, x.SortOrder })
    .Distinct
    .OrderBy(Function(x) x.SortOrder)
    .Select(Function(x) x.Month)
```

This assumes that the `SortOrder` for each month will be the same across all months.