# LINQ statement using Orderby and Distinct in sub query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Hi I have following LINQ query, that I am trying to orderby and select distinct values.

```
 var records = (from c in db.pt
                       join y in db.pro on c.id equals y.id
                       where c.id == id
                       select new proj
                           {
                               id = cid,
                               newStructure = new List<team>
                                   {
                                       new teamP
                                           {
                                               t_id = c.p_id,
                                               full_name = c.per.last_name + " ," + c.per.last_name,

                                           }
                                   }
                           }).ToList().OrderBy("full_name").distinct();
```

On the above query on OrderBy I get intellisence error "cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying type arguments explicitly"
Please let me know how to fix this error. Thanks

Comment: One comment - the call to `ToList` will drag all the data to your process, at which point you will order and distinct locally. Is this intentional as you should really be letting your DB perform the order and distinct.

Comment: **1.** Why do you need `y in db.pro`? What does the join does? (it's an inner join, so it can be a filter - is that intentional?) **2.** Classes and Properties should be in PascalCase: `proj`, `team`, `last_name `, etc. You might have your own convention, but it's awkward **3.** What is the point of both `OrderBy` and `Distinct`? I doubt `Distinct` is guaranteed to keep the order, so this is pretty useless: [LINQ to SQL does not generate ORDER BY when DISTINCT is used?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9764978/7586)

Answer (score 0):

Do Like this.

```
var records = (from c in db.pt
               join y in db.pro on c.id equals y.id
                  where c.id == id
                         select new proj
                          {
                             id = cid,
                              newStructure = new List<team>
                                {
                                    new teamP
                                       {
                                           t_id = c.p_id,
                                           full_name = c.per.last_name + " ," +                         c.per.last_name,

                                       }
                               }
                       }).distinct().ToList();
```

Add This line

```
records=records.OrderBy(x=>x.fullname == "Full_Name");
```

Comment: Out of interest, why call `ToList` before calling `Distinct`?