# How can I Skip and Take objects until I have 10 distinct ones in LINQ to Entities?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

This is the problematic code:

```
var distinctCatNames = allCats.Select(c => c.CatName).Distinct();

if (skip.HasValue) distinctCatNames = distinctCatNames .Skip(skip.Value);
if (take.HasValue) distinctCatNames = distinctCatNames .Take(take.Value);

var distinctCatNameList= distinctCatNames .ToList();
```

If you imagine I have a list of 100 cats, I want to select the 10 distinct names. It's going into a paged list so it has to use skip and take.

The above won't work, because it has to be ordered with OrderBy.

If I put the OrderBy after the distinct, I can't do Skip and Take because the result is an IOrderedQueryable, not an IQueryable (compiler error).

If I do it before, the error says `DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable.`

I need to make sure that under the hood it's translating my query properly, because there may be a lot of cats so I want to ensure it generates SQL that incorporates the skip/take in the query rather than getting ALL cats and then doing it on that collection.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to SQL does not generate ORDER BY when DISTINCT is used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764978/linq-to-sql-does-not-generate-order-by-when-distinct-is-used)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to order the items but then simply type the variable you store it in as an `IQueryable`, rather than an `IOrderedQueryable`:

```
var distinctCatNames = allCats.Select(c => c.CatName)
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(name => name)
    .AsQueryable();
```

Comment: `<facepalm>`. Hopefully linq to entities won't throw a fit about the conversion and will still work nicely. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, same error `DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable.`

Comment: @SLC What's the type of `CatName`?  One would think, being a name, it'd be a string.  Apparently it's not.

Comment: It is. I think it's a linq to entities problem, I suspect it doesn't like trying to skip and take on an ordered a list of strings.

Comment: @SLC That's not the case at all.  It most certainly can do that.  Are you certain that it is in fact a string value that is mapped to a database column?  Because the query provider is saying that it's not.

Comment: It's definitely a string, nvarchar(256) in the database. It works if I `ToList()` it before the skip and take so something is going weird in EF.

Comment: @SLC In that case you're ordering on the database side, not on the client side,s o you shouldn't be getting any errors about not being able to order on that type.

Comment: Indeed. I've changed the logic to this and it seems to work, so maybe an issue with `AsQueryable`: `allCats.Select(c => c.CatName).Distinct().OrderBy(c => c).Select(c => c);`